# Remove last character in dynamic string

Tags: string, powershell

I am having issues with removing the last character of a dynamically populated string. The last character is a `','` and I can remove it but the problem is that when I print out the list the comma is still there. To create the string I read information in from a CSV into an array. I then take everything in the array and convert it to the final format.

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $CSVArray.Length; $i++) {
  $longString = $longString + "'" + $CSVArray[$i] + "',"
}
```

Then I find the length of the string,

```
$length = $longString.Length
```

Finally I remove the last character,

```
$longString = $longString.Substring($length - 1).Replace(",", "")
```

When I output `$longString.Substring($length - 1)` I get just the comma but when I output $longString after doing the replace it still has the comma at the end.

How can I remove the very last character from longString?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply `-join` the array:

```
$longString = "'" + ($CSVArray -join "','") + "'"
```

Comment: I am not familiar with -join so I could be using it wrong but when I Write-Host of $longString right after running this line the comma is still on the end.

Comment: @aDroidman That clearly is not possible if you replaced your loop with the line from my answer. Please provide evidence.

Comment: Aaaa I see now. Sorry it does work. The problem was with the day I implemented the above code.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ansgar Wiechers mentions, using `-join` in your case is better. For other strings/cases this would work:

```
$longString = $longString.Substring(0,$longString.Length -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Deletes the last Charakter:

```
$LongString = $LongString ".$"
```

Deletes the 2 last Charakters:

```
$LongString = $LongString "..$"
```

As so on!